# JDBC mysql with latin1 charset

Tags: mysql, jdbc, character-encoding

I've a simple java script that use jdbc to get data from mysql table (CHARSET=latin1). I've chinese words in a field and it looks correct when I do a select from mysql prompt but when I run it from the java it display incorrect characters.

The jdbc url I've this and seems not help.

jdbc:mysql://dev-mt01:3306/mundotrack?characterEncoding=Cp1252&useUnicode=yes

I also added this in the url characterSetResults=Cp1252 and seems still doesn't help.

I got the Cp1252 from this page.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Only the first 256 Unicode characters are included in the `Latin 1` codepage; Chinese characters cannot be encoded in `Latin 1`. You should switch to using `UTF-8`, both in the DB and your client software.

Comment: Better yet, `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Comment: did you find a solution for that?